# Can't count '|' symbols in a .c file

Tags: c, file, fgetc, charactercount

Basically I have to write a program that counts all kinds of different symbols in a .c file. I got it to work with all of the needed symbols except the vertical line '`|`'. For some reason it just won't count them.

Here's the method I'm using:

```
int countGreaterLesserEquals(char filename[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    FILE *f;
    int temp = 0; // ASCII code of the character
    int capital = 0;
    int lesser = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    int comments = 0;
    int lines = 0;
    int spc = 0;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File is invalid\\empty.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((temp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

        if (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z') {
            capital++;
        }
        else if (temp >= 'A' && temp <= 'Z') {
            lesser++;
        }
        else if( temp == '/') temp = fgetc(fp); {
            if(temp == '/')
                comments++;             
        }

        if (temp >= '0' && temp <= '9') {
            numbers++;
        }
        if (temp == '|') {
            spc++;
        }
        if (temp == '\n') {
            lines++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Indent your code properly. 2) Show the declaration and initialization of the variables

Comment: try to check for '||'?

Comment: Nope checking for '||' doesn't work either.

Comment: Why did you change `|` to `l`?

Comment: "it just won't count" is not a **specific** problem description. Provide a [mcve]. Also note C does not support _methods_, only _functions_.

Comment: You may try to search these: ['|'] or [ |] or (alt + 179) or (alt + 124)

Comment: `islower(temp)` and `isupper(temp)` would be preferable to your range checks

Comment: Suggest posting a sample `filename` contents.

Comment: Since post code never prints `spc` there is no reason for the compiler to actual count them.  Code does not demonstrate "For some reason it just won't count them".  Post true code with true sample input.

Answer (score 3):

On this line:

`else if( temp == '/') temp = fgetc(fp); {`

I believe you have a misplaced `{`. As I understand it should come before `temp = fgetc(fp);`..

You can easily avoid such an errors if following coding style guidelines placing each expression on it's own line and indenting the code properly.

Update: And this `fgetc` is a corner case. What if you read past `EOF` here? You are not checking this error.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, some compiler warnings:

- 'f' : unreferenced local variable
- not all control paths return a value

So, `f` can be removed, and the function should return a value on success too. It's always a good idea to set compiler warnings at the highest level.

Then, there is a problem with:

```
else if( temp == '/') temp = fgetc(fp); {
    if(temp == '/')
        comments++;             
}
```

Check the `;` at the end of the `else`. This means the block following it, is always executed. Also, for this `fgetc()` there is no check for `EOF` or an error.

Also, if `temp` is a `/`, but the following character is not, it will be skipped, so we need to put the character back into the stream (easiest solution in this case).

Here is a full example:

```
int countGreaterLesserEquals(char filename[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int temp     = 0; // ASCII code of the character
    int capital  = 0;
    int lesser   = 0;
    int numbers  = 0;
    int comments = 0;
    int lines    = 0;
    int spc      = 0;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File is invalid\\empty.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while ((temp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {

        // check characters - check most common first
        if      (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z') lesser++;
        else if (temp >= 'A' && temp <= 'Z') capital++;
        else if (temp >= '0' && temp <= '9') numbers++;
        else if (temp == '|')                spc++;
        else if (temp == '\n')               lines++;
        else if( temp == '/')
            if ((temp = fgetc(fp)) == EOF)
                break; // handle error/eof
            else
                if(temp == '/')              comments++;
                else ungetc(temp, fp); // put character back into the stream
    }

    fclose (fp); // close as soon as possible

    printf("capital:  %d\nlesser:   %d\ncomments: %d\n"
           "numbers:  %d\nspc:      %d\nlines:    %d\n",
           capital, lesser, comments, numbers, spc, lines
    );

    return 1;
}
```

While it is usually recommended to put `if` statements inside curly braces, I think in this case we can place them on the same line for clarity.

Each `if` can be preceded with an `else` in this case. That way the program doesn't have to check the remaining cases when one is already found. The checks for the most common characters are best placed first for the same reason (but that was the case).

As an alternative you could use [`islower(temp)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/islower/), [`isupper(temp)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/) and [`isdigit(temp)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) for the first three cases.

---

**Performance**:

For the sake of completeness: while this is probably an exercise on small files, for larger files the data should be read in buffers for better performance (or even using memory mapping on the file).

**Update**, [@SteveSummit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923896/steve-summit)'s comment on `fgetc` performance:

> Good answer, but I disagree with your note about performance at the
>   end. `fgetc` already is buffered! So the performance of straightforward
>   code like this should be fine even for large inputs; there's typically
>   no need to complicate the code due to concerns about "efficiency".

Whilst this comment seemed to be valid at first, I really wanted to know what the real difference in performance would be (since I never use `fgetc` I hadn't tested this before), so I wrote a little test program:

Open a large file and sum every byte into a `uint32_t`, which is comparable to scanning for certain chars as above. Data was already cached by the OS disk cache (since we're testing performance of the functions/scans, not the reading speed of the hard disk). While the example code above was most likely for small files, I thought I might put the test results for larger files here as well.

Those were the average results:

```
- using fgetc                                        : 8770
- using a buffer and scan the chars using a pointer  :  188
- use memory mapping and scan chars using a pointer  :  118
```

Now, I was pretty sure using buffers and memory mapping would be faster (I use those all the time for larger data), the difference in speed is even bigger than expected. Ok, there might be some possible optimizations for `fgetc`, but even if those would double the speed, the difference would still be high.

**Bottom line**: Yes, it is worth the effort to optimize this for larger files. For example, if processing the data of a file takes 1 second with buffers/mmap, it would take over a minute with `fgetc`!

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree with your note about performance at the end.  `fgetc` already *is* buffered!  So the performance of straightforward code like this should be fine even for large inputs; there's typically no need to complicate the code due to concerns about "efficiency".

Comment: @SteveSummit - You may be right (I haven't done a performance comparison between fgetc and say mmap yet -- ok, had a quick look at the generated code, the first fgetc is optimized away, the second not -- but while creating/reading a buffer, all chars seem to be checked first (newline etc), and moved). Buffer is read in via user mode. - so I'm pretty sure memory mapping (or even user defined buffers) will be faster. But I'll remove that note, it doesn't belong there anyway (I just added it to be complete in case someone posted a comment about fgetc() not being the right tool for that.. :)

Comment: @SteveSummit - Ok, I wrote a small test program to check it - the results (time taken): fgetc: 8770, user buffer: 188, memory mapping: 118. The difference is even a lot higher than I expected.

Comment: Unclear about `use memory mapping and loop with a pointer`.  This may be limited by the size of memory.  The other methods would have no scaling problem with large files.  Other method: opening the file in binary mode.

Comment: @chux - Memory mapping and buffers would scale too of course (views are created on a mapping), and scanned (I'll change the wording) with a pointer instead of fgetc. Both are (almost) automatically in binary mode.

Comment: 1) So how much saving is due to binary vs text mode - sounds like an uneven comparison.?  2) I was think that memory mapping may have issues for files that well exceed memory space.  Have you tried comparing memory mapping with `fgetc()` with files of that magnitude?

Comment: @chux - 1) My 'Performance' remark was about using buffers (of course binary) vs `fgetc()`, the comment stated that performance wouldn't be a big difference, so I tested. The original goal was to scan a file for certain characters. Opening the file with "rb" didn't make a difference for fgetc, as expeced. So my point is that scanning for chars can be a lot faster than with the so called 'optimized' fgetc (and I wanted to know that for myself too). 2) in next comment.

Comment: @chux -  2) Files of 1TB can be memory mapped without a problem, only the mapped view (sliding when needed) should fit in memory for best performance (Windows) - on linux there is no notion of a view as far as I know, just doing another mmap should be fine. This is always faster than user mode buffers, because data doesn't get copied from kernel to user mode, memory mapping works directly on the kernel mode disk cache, that's what makes it so fast.

Comment: @chux - 2) continued.. -  As for comparing with large files: I work a lot with files far bigger than memory, only using buffers or memory mapping, and this will always be (a lot) faster than fgetc or (buffered) streaming.

Comment: Good hard work - unfortunately for a post that is unclear.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: All this discussion about performance is somewhat tangential, but one point that's been missed is that no one ever uses `fgetc`; the preferred method is `getc`, which is likely to be significantly faster.